# Blur image function worked incorrectly

Tags: python

I implemented blur image function without using any libraries in Python. Input image is RGB image, output image is blurred RGB image. I tried in some images and found black pixels in the border of blurred images. I couldn'f fix this problem. How could I solve this problem on my code ?
My code was here:

```
def blur(image, ksize): # blur image function
  height, width, channel = image.shape[:] # get height, width, channel in shape of image 

  array_channel = []
  array_height = []
  array_width = []

  for i in range(channel):
    array_channel.append(np.float64(0))
  for j in range(width):
    array_width.append(array_channel)
  for k in range(height):
    array_height.append(array_width)
  new_image = np.array(array_height)
  
  for i in range(height - ksize + 1): # iterate vertical pixel in height
   for j in range(width - ksize + 1): # iterate horizontal pixel in width
    for k in range(channel): # iterate channel
      for l in range(ksize): # iterate ksize
        temp = (float(image[i + l, j + l][k]) * float(image[i - l, j - l][k]) * \
                float(image[i, j + l][k]) * float(image[i, j - l][k]) * \
                float(image[i + l, j][k]) * float(image[i - l, j][k]) * \
                float(image[i + l, j - l][k]) * float(image[i - l, j + l][k])) ** (1/8)
        # calculate temp value
        new_image[i, j][k] += temp / ksize # calculate pixels in range of ksize 
  return new_image # return new image
```

Comment: first use `print()` to see what values you have in variables. You may need to run `range(height)` and `range(wdith)` instead of `range(height-ksize+`)` and `range(width - ksize + 1)`. Using `range(height-ksize)` you skip some pixels and you get black margin.

Comment: I will try. Thanks to your opinion.